# How to combine two rows in a table postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Normaly I wouldn't ask this question however I have a bit of unique situation where I'm having troudle in How to do it.

I have a table `A` as follows:

```
uniqueid , itemid, quantity, selected
1            2455     10        TRUE
2            7458     50        FALSE
3            58494    20.6      FALSE
4            2455     20        TRUE
```

I need to write a combine function that takes rows which are `TRUE` of the same part and combine them to one row (with the updated `quantity`).

meaning I want to get:

```
uniqueid , itemid, quantity, selected
1            2455     30        FASLE
2            7458     50        FALSE
3            58494    20.6      FALSE/TRUE (doesn't matter)
```

OR:

```
uniqueid , itemid, quantity, selected
2            7458     50        FALSE
3            58494    20.6      FALSE
4            2455     30        FALSE/TRUE (doesn't matter)
```

My function doesn't get any paramenters... I need some method which I can identfy and work with the rows which are selected.
First I thought of doing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1()
  RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
declare 
    ROW RECORD
begin
for ROW in select * from A where selected
    LOOP
        do combine code     
    end loop;
end;                
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

However this code will not work as after each combine two rows become one. In the above example the loop will generate two iterations, but I need only 1 iteration.. only 1 combine action neeeded.

I only need assistance in how to get the structure of the function - loop? if? how to save the rows?. no need to write the combine code.

**To make it simpler** assume there can be only two rows which `selected` is `TRUE`.

**Note**: `func1` is supposed to **save** the new state into `A`.

Comment: Why is the `selected` column for itemid = 2455 suddenly `false` in the expected output if the actual data contains a `true`? Also do you want to permanently change (=update) the table or do you just want a query that returns this result?

Comment: After the function runs.. all selctions must be changed to false.. Sorry if it confused you... it has no meaning for the question.

Comment: So you want to _update_ the table (i.e. delete rows that are duplicated), not just _select_ from it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to do this in a union - in that case it also doesn't matter how many rows there are with `selected = false`:

```
select min(uniqueid) as uniqueid,
       itemid, 
       sum(quantity) as quantity, 
       false as selected
from a 
where selected
group by itemid
union all
select uniqueid,
       itemid,
       quantity,
       selected
from a
where not selected
order by 1;
```

---

**Edit** after it has been clarified that the table should be modified.

You can do this with a data modifying CTE. In the first step the sum of the quantity is updated and in the second step the no longer needed rows are deleted:

```
with updated as (
  -- this updates the lowest uniqueid with the total sum
  -- of all rows. If you want to keep/update the highest
  -- uniqueid change the min() to max()
  update a 
    set quantity = t.total_sum,
        selected = false
  from (
    select min(uniqueid) as uniqueid,
           itemid, 
           sum(quantity) as total_sum
    from a 
    where selected
    group by itemid
  ) t
  where t.uniqueid = a.uniqueid 
  returning a.uniqueid
)
-- this now deletes the rows that are still marked
-- as "selected" and where not updated
delete from a
where selected
  and uniqueid not in (select uniqueid from updated);
```

This assumes that the `uniqueid` column is indeed unique (e.g. a primary key or has a unique index/constraint defined). The value for `selected` column has to be changed in order for this to work. So it *does* matter if `selected` is set to false during this process.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a try with a `UNION` maybe

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(t.uniqueid) AS uniqueid,
    t.itemid,
    SUM(t.quantity) AS quantity,
    FALSE AS selected
  FROM table_name t
    WHERE t.selected = TRUE
    GROUP BY t.itemid
  UNION
  SELECT t.uniqueid,
    t.itemid,
    t.quantity,
    t.selected
  FROM table_name t
    WHERE t.selected = FALSE) u
  ORDER BY u.uniqueid ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell anything about uniqueid transmutation and selected column as well, but I assume you want smth like this:

```
select distinct uniqueid,itemid,quantity,selected
from (
select 
 case when selected then max(uniqueid) over (partition by selected) else uniqueid end uniqueid 
 , itemid
 , case when selected then sum(quantity) over (partition by selected) else quantity end quantity 
 , false  selected
from t113
) init
order by 1
;
```